# How to create a model attached to two users? Without interfering with attr_accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, attr-accessible

I am making a game, and have a Game model and a User model.

The Game model looks like the following:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :first_user, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key =>'first_user_id'
  belongs_to :second_user, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key =>'second_user_id'
  validates_presence_of :first_user, :second_user

  attr_accessible :created_at, :finished_datetime, :first_user_id, :second_user_id, :status, :winner_user_id
  ...
```

Now, in my controller for the game, I call Game.new.  I'm certain that it is being called with current_user and challenge_user, because I checked with logging.

```
Game.new(:first_user => current_user, :second_user => challenge_user)
```

Unfortunately, I get the error:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: first_user, second_user
```

I don't understand this since I used attr_accessible, not attr_accessor, so they should be assignable.  What should I do differently, Rails?

Comment: You don't need to specify `:foreign_key` if it can be inferred form `belongs_to`. Just `class_name` has to be enough.

Comment: This is wrong: `attr_accessible :first_user, :secound_user` this is right: `attr_accessible :first_user_id, :secound_user_id` because you dont add the accessible to the association you add it for the attribute name!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you pass in on e.g `.new` or `.update_attributes` as attributes is "mass-assignment". You need to assign them "manually", like this:

```
@game = current_user.games.new(params[:my_game_mass_assignment_attributes])
@game.second_user = # your second user
```

Assigning one attribute at a time is not "mass-assignment" and will work for security reasons (see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment)